# karate| env specific config file

Tags: config, karate

karate framework| I am trying to create multiple karate-config.js file for different env like 'test', 'stage' can somebody help me with an example how I can call env specific config values from different karate config file.
I refer this https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/karate-config-contract.js
 but doesn't clarify what exactly need to do for calling different config.

Comment: I really want to understand, is the documentation not good enough, please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config

Comment: @PeterThomas: You are tired answering these questions, aren't you?.. let me help you :-)

Comment: @Peter thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the [karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs) explains how to check the `karate.env` property in your `karate-config.js` in order to set configurations and variables depending on your environment.

An other way to archive different configurations per environment is explained here: [environment-specific-config](https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config)

All these approaches solves the issue, to configure different urls for example in your test cases.
Hence, there is no need to call or check for the environment in your feature file in order to get different configuration values. It's done by karate. Just refer to the variables you assigned in `karate-config.js`.

You just do something like:

```
Background:
* url baseUrls.userSystem
```

Where your `karate-config.js` could look like:

```
function fn() {

    if (!env) {
        env = 'local';
    }

   var config = {
        baseUrls : {
             userSystem : "http://localhost"
        }

   }
   if (env === 'dev') {
        config.baseUrls.userSystem = "http://usersystem.default.svc"
   }

   return config   
}
```

The approach above demonstrate how to use just one `karate-config.js` for all enviroments. One file for all.

If you want to create a `karate-config-<env>.js` per enviroment, follow the [environment-specific-config](https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config) documentation.

You will find here https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java a default `karate-config.js` that will be evaluated for every environment. The `karate-config-contract.js` will only be evaluated after the `karate-config.js` file has been evaluated if and only if the `karate.env` property is `contract`.

Please read the [karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config). Peter did a great job to document nearly every little feature karate offers.

Comment: If i am running single scenario or feature file manually (with out using cmd ) karate-config-<env>.js file not executing only main config properties are reachable why? do i need to set any additional thing apart from karate.env @Peter can you help me

Comment: How do you execute/run the scenario?

Comment: If i am running through IntelliJ shortcut options(by right click on test or feature file and click on run) in that case only main config file is running, it is not redirecting to env specific file-@Peter

Comment: @CharuGupta: How do you specify the environment via IntelliJ?